# how can read images in android 11?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-11

I have already updated the Android Image cropper library. [Android Image cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)
And I know the android 11 new features. [android 11 new features](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11)
Anyone can help me. For the image read from the camera caption.

Get URI to image received from capture by camera.

```
    public static Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri(@NonNull Context context) {
    Uri outputFileUri = null;
    File getImage = context.getExternalCacheDir();
    if (getImage != null) {
        //This stetment are work in android 10.
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImage.getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
       //how can i read image in android 11?
       // outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName(), getImage);
    }
    return outputFileUri;
}
```

Select image from activity or Fragment

```
 CropImage
                    .activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setBorderCornerColor(Color.RED)
                    .setBorderLineColor(Color.CYAN).
                    setAutoZoomEnabled(true)
                    .setRequestedSize(300, 300)
                    .start(AbcActivity.this));
```

And also I try in android 11. [Take photos](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java)
But onActivityResult Intent data are null in android 11.

Comment: `Get URI to image received from capture by camera.` No. That is an uri you build yourself. Has nothing  to to with a received image from a camera. You will use it for the camera i think. And further we do not see where you use that uri. And also not onActivityResult code where you get a null. For which intent? We dont know what you do. We dont know what is happening.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to read the image from the camera caption. like select image>open a camera>capture. then will set on view.

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what you do. And i see no code.